# Selecting an item in a combobox disables the same item in all others

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Suppose I have mulitple comboboxes and each have an identical list of items.

If an item is selected in any one of those comboboxes, then the given item needs to be disabled in all of the other comboboxes.

If the user changes the selection of any of the comboboxes, then the item that was previously selected should be free for selection across all of the comboboxes.

This is to prevent the user from selecting duplicate items across all the comboboxes.

I am aware that this sounds like a group of checkboxes can do this, but in this situation I cannot do that.  Each combobox is associated with something else, and they are all pointing to a common pool of items.  I need to know what is associated with what.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb1">
    <ComboBoxItem>asdf</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>qwerty</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>1234</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>zxcv</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox x:Name="cb2">
    <ComboBoxItem>asdf</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>qwerty</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>1234</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>zxcv</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox x:Name="cb3">
    <ComboBoxItem>asdf</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>qwerty</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>1234</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>zxcv</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: The question isn't answerable in its current form as it's too broad and non-specific. The easiest way to address this would be include some code. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Code sample added, although there isn't much to show.  It's as I had described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the list itens are identical, when the user chooses a combobox, you can loop through the itens of each combobox and disable the item that has the same value.

Answer (score -1):

taking this is a web project you may use jquery to validate the comboboxes. you should give an id to each combo and validate the "onChange" method, then if a combo is changed, the others will be lock or change depending their values.

Comment: Unfortunately the question's tagged with C# and WPF, which is going to rule out a web project.